# How to get jenkins parameter in selenium / java on run time

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I am working on a automation project which uses selenium with webdriver (Java) to record the steps and maven + jenkins to execute the scripts .

Script has been completed and working fine. Issue is I have to deploy it over the 3 environments QAMachine, Staging.

We initiate the build link like http://testsite.com:8080/jenkins/job/FaizanTest/ via our testing portal

What I want is to enhance. 
so that I can access the link (modified link lets say http://testsite.com:8080/jenkins/job/FaizanTest?env=qa OR env=stag) and the build auto executed on the specified machine.

I know this is called parametrized build and I know how to put parameter on jenkins but the issue is how I find in selenium/java which uses property file to execute URL (environment)

Answer (score 0):

If you user parametrized build you can use build step "Execute Shell":

```
echo 'env='${ENVIRONMENT} > suite.properties
```

where, 
`ENVIRONMENT` is Jenkins variable which was defined in parameters,
`env.properties` properties file in your framework.

This script will write this variable to properties file, so you will be able to read it from file in your selenium/java framework.